# Google Charts - Avoid showing negative values in yAxis

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have the following code:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'People'],
    ['2010',0]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data,
           {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
            width:600, height:400,
            hAxis: {title: "Year"},
            backgroundColor: 'none'
           }
      );
}
```

Which gives me the following chart [image: chart]

How can I do to avoid showing negative values in the yAxis? I have tried adding
`vAxis: {minValue:0}` without any luck.

There is a playground/sandbox for these charts: [Google Charts Playground](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#column_chart)

​

Answer (score 58):

You need to set viewWindowMode as explicit

```
vAxis: {viewWindowMode: "explicit", viewWindow:{ min: 0 }}
```

Comment: Now this on the other hand does seem to fix my problem. Thank you!

Comment: `viewWindowMode: "explicit"` is no longer needed as it is now deprecated.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options

Comment: Side Note: when you are using curvy lines with the Line Charts then it will produce a negative number, if you use straight lines it will not.

Answer (score 5):

`viewWindowMode: "explicit"` is deprecated in current version which uses: `vAxis.viewWindow.min`:

```
vAxis: {
    viewWindow: {
        min: 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Rightly said, `viewWindowMode: "explicit"` is deprecated. 
[Soure](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options)

Answer (score 0):

It was not working form me. I needed to add the max value:`max:1`

The negative axis only appears if all the values are 0, so, for not bounding in the max, I only put the vAxis if there are no positives values (using PHP).

The example of my code is:

```
                $hayPositivos = false;
            foreach($valores as $valor){
                $html[]=",
                ['".$valor['dia']."', ".intval($valor['validadas']).",      ".intval($valor['totales'])."]";
                if(!$hayPositivos && (intval($valor['validadas']) >0 || intval($valor['totales']) >0)){
                    $hayPositivos = true;
                }
            }

                    $html[]="]);

                    var options = {
                      title: '".t('News by time:').$periodo_nombre."',
                      legend: { position: 'bottom' }";
                    if(!$hayPositivos){
                        $html[] = ",
                        vAxis: {
                          viewWindow: {min: 0, max:1}
                        }";
                    }
                      
                    $html[] = "};
```

And this is how it is seen:

[If all values are negative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzrvu.jpg)

[If there is any positive value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPe5I.jpg)

Comment: Thanks, adding `max: 1` fixed it, as only adding `min: 0` didn't