# angular google chart haxis in middle if values are zero

Tags: google-visualization

when i create a chart (with google chart) with all the values setted to zero, the haxis is in the middle of the chart.

How can i stuck it at the bottom ?

here is the code :

```
function drawChart() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
data.addColumn('number', 'Average Revenue');
data.addRows([
  ['2004', 0],
  ['2005', 0],
  ['2006', 0],
  ['2007', 0]
]);

var options = {
  title: 'Revenue by Year',
  seriesType: "bars",
  series: {1: {type: "line"}},  
  vAxis: {title: 'Year',
          titleTextStyle:{color: 'red'}},
    colors:['red','black']
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/boj6ztLo/

thanks

Comment: solved with this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937342/google-charts-avoid-showing-negative-values-in-yaxis(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937342/google-charts-avoid-showing-negative-values-in-yaxis)

Answer (score 1):

set following config option...

`vAxis.viewWindow.min: 0`

see following working snippet...

```js
function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Average Revenue');
  data.addRows([
    ['2004', 0],
    ['2005', 0],
    ['2006', 0],
    ['2007', 0]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Revenue by Year',
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {
      1: {
        type: 'line'
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Year',
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: 'red'
      },
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0
      }
    },
    colors:['red','black']
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**note**

recommend **not using** `jsapi` to load the library, according to [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader (`loader.js`) from now on.

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

this will also change the `load` statement to...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```